# Swift 3 Reflection - Iterating over properties

Tags: swift, reflection, swift3

Trying to write a convenience `toString()` method that lists all properties and their assigned values of an object.

```
class FooModel
{
    func toString() -> String
    {
        var result = "[\(String(describing: type(of: self))) "
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        mirror.children.forEach
        {
            child in
                result += "\(child.label): \(child.value), "
        }
        return "\(result)]"
    }
}

class FooProject : FooModel
{
    var id = 0
    var name = ""
    var announcement:String?
    var showAnnouncement = false
    var isCompleted = false
    var completedOn:String?
    var suiteMode = 0
    var url = ""
}
```

Output:

```
[FooProject Optional("id"): 0, Optional("name"): , Optional("announcement"): nil, Optional("showAnnouncement"): false, Optional("isCompleted"): false, Optional("completedOn"): nil, Optional("suiteMode"): 0, Optional("url"): , ]
```

First, it doesn't list the actual values but the default values. Why is that?
Second, is there a way to get rid of the `Optional` encapsulation?

Comment: Why are `id` and `name` listed as `Optional()`?

Comment: @NicolasMiari yeah that's what I'm wondering, too.

Comment: You can use child.label! to get rid of optional encapsulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation about `Child`  [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mirror/child) :

**Child**

> An element of the reflected instance’s structure. The optional label may be used when appropriate, e.g. to represent the name of a
>   stored property or of an active enum case, and will be used for lookup
>   when Strings are passed to the descendant method.

Since type child in mirror is defined as

```
typealias Child = (label: String?, value: Any)
```

Therefore all names are printed as Optionals.

To get the label names you can use optional binding

I have made some changes and tried this in playground:

```
class FooModel
{
    func toString() -> String
    {
        var result = "[\(String(describing: type(of: self))) "
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        mirror.children.forEach
            {
                child in
                print(child)
                if let label = child.label {
                    result += "\(label): \(child.value), "
                }
        }
        return "\(result)]"
    }
}

class FooProject : FooModel
{
    var id = 0
    var name = ""
    var announcement:String!
    var showAnnouncement = false
    var isCompleted = false
    var completedOn:String!
    var suiteMode = 0
    var url = ""

    init(id: Int, name: String, completedOn: String) {
        self.completedOn = completedOn
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        //...
    }
}

let fooProj = FooProject(id: 10, name: "Name", completedOn: "Sunday")
print(fooProj.toString())
```

Ouptut is :

```
[FooProject id: 10, name: Name, announcement: nil, showAnnouncement: false, isCompleted: false, completedOn: Sunday, suiteMode: 0, url: , ]
```

HTH..

Comment: Thanks! But just adding a `!` after label does seem to be sufficient.